# Can we add a valid value for an unknown variable in an equation by multiplying both sides of the equation by the same number/equation?

Tags: problem-solving

I have two related questions.

I was solving some problems on the matter of (*Let's call it "rule X"*):

> $a^n - b^n = (a - b)(a^{n - 1} + a^{n - 2}b \space + ... + \space ab^{n - 2} + b^{n - 1})$

And at some point I encountered this equation, where $x$ has to be found:

> $(1 + x + x^2 + x^3)(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7) = (1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5)^2$

Considering the the topic, I did it this way:

1. Multiplying both sides by $(x - 1)^2$
2. Following the *rule X* we can already simplify the equation as following: $(x^4 - 1)(x^8 - 1) = (x^6 - 1)^2$
3. Simplifying it further: $x^{12} - x^8 - x^4 + 1 = x^{12} - 2x^6 + 1 \implies x^8 + x^4 = 2x^6 \implies x^4(x^4 + 1) = 2x^6 \implies x^4 + 1 = 2x^2 \implies x^4 - 2x^2 + 1 = 0 \implies (x^2 - 1)^2 = 0$ 
   And the valid values for $x$ are only $±1$

**But**, if we take the initial equation *before the step (1)*, you can easily see that the only valid values for $x$ are $0$ and $-1$. I couldn't figure out what's wrong, because my calculations seemed correct, until I understood that I was actually just adding a new valid value for $x$. I thought that mathematically I didn't do anything wrong, since there's a simple rule that states we can multiply/divide/add/subtract, *whatever algebraic operations we want*, both sides of an equation on the same number/equation. So I'm left with two questions:

1. **Can you perform any additional algebraic operations on both sides of an equation if it changes the final answer ? If no, how do I solve the equation?**
2. **Weather you can or no, coming from the way I solved this problem, there must be now three valid values for $x$: $-1$, $0$, and $1$, but as you saw I got only two valid values. Where was I wrong in my calculations ?**

Answer (score 0):

If you have an equation a = b, and multiply by (x^2 - 1), the result will have a solution when x^2 - 1 = 0, that is if x = +/- 1, because your new equation is just 0=0 in that case.

You solve the new equation. Then you check manually if x = +/- 1 are actually solutions of the original equation. And if these two are not solutions of the new equation, that is highly suspicious and you need to check what is going on.

PS You multiplied by (x-1)^2, which is 0 if x=1 and in no other case. So you expect a solution x=1 to be added and no other.

PPS The rule is that you won’t lose solutions unless you divide both sides by zero. But you gain solutions if you multiply by zero.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I don't think that this answers any of the questions I asked.